# Partial classes or inheritance

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inheritance

I have a god class, let's call it `Aphordite` that is already 1000 lines of codes, I'm writing a list of methods that checks feasibility on that class and it's 500+ lines of codes.

Now I don't know if it's better to put these methods inside the class (which will grow to 1500+ lines), make a partial class (but I read it's a solution for code generators) using inheritance or make a static class containing only these methods.

Considering these method will be called only by `Aphrodite` what is the best solution?

Comment: Both Partial classes and inheritance are not intended to do what you want. You need to give your problem specifically to get a better answer.

Comment: If I had to make a guess at gun point, I would say that this is exactly the purpose of partial classes, but 99% that's 'fixing' the symptoms, not the cause. I agree some more specifics are required.

Comment: Partial classes are purely organizational, whereas it sounds as though your problem is a God class which needs refactoring.

Comment: "Checks feasibility" is too vague. Classes need cohesive responsibilities, so try to come up with theme for grouping the responsibilities. Specific questions will get specific answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way is to split the whole code (1500+ lines) into more different subclasses. Then they should inherit from your main class Aphrodite.

Then you have the possibility to run all methods from your main class.

A second less-good way is to create a static class Aphrodite which creates static singleton objects of all the new sub classes in public properties.
With that you can call each subclass from your main class like this:

```
// names are only for example :)
Aphrodite.Wine.Drink();
Aphrodite.Wine.NotDrive();
Aphrodite.Bottle.FillWithWine();
Aphrodite.Bottle.DrinkFromBottle();
```

Comment: Architecture-wise is still a good solution to have subclasses only inherited by one class?

Comment: No, thats the reason why i wrote "less-good". But it's one way of many :)

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely *have* to do it this way, you could define an inner class within `Aphrodite` (and within one partial definition of it) and make that a static class to contain these methods. At least until you refactor it.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the ["Pure fabrication" GRASP pattern](http://books.google.ca/books?id=tuxQAAAAMAAJ&q=isbn:0131489062&dq=isbn:0131489062&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nfwoU6nZC8rkyAGsxIDAAQ&redir_esc=y) (sounds like you're desperate):

> Who is responsible when you are desperate, and do not want to violate high cohesion and low coupling?
>
> Assign a highly cohesive set of responsibilities to an artificial or convenience "behavior" class that does not represent a problem domain concept -- something made up, in order to support high cohesion, low coupling, and reuse.

It's also as simple as an ["Extract class" refactoring](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractClass.html). But really, if you don't give more details, it's hard to say.